# What is that? component identification

Tags: components

What is that? A capacitor or something else?

Sorry for the bad quality... It is labeled with: [strange symbol] X50 YKRA
[image: unknow component]

Comment: Where did you find it? Power supply?

Comment: Look like a polyfuse to me, with 'capacitor' as second guess. Is there any marking on the PCB?

Comment: It is on a interface platine between a SPS Siemens S7-1200 and a "Fischertechnik" training modell. The platine works with 24V and the component is placed between VCC.

Comment: Between the Vcc and what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [TE Connectivity RXEF050](http://www.te.com/catalog/pn/en/RF2567-000?RQPN=RXEF050) resettable PolySwitch.

[image]